# Privacy Policy in Play Console, error with Contact List

Tags: android, publish, google-play-console

[image]

I upload my app to Google Play, and the upload rejected by this error:

**Your app is uploading users' Contact List information without disclosing it in the privacy policy in Play Console.**

I filled data safety section(Contacts) in different ways, but still Play Console reject my app

Comment: Have you mentioned the Contact  List uploading in your Privacy Policy page ?

Comment: Do you think it is possible to do so? @AshutoshOjha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your Privacy Policy, and mention this in a clear manner.

**Note:** Make sure you have a link to your Privacy Policy in app also.

Answer (score 0):

After Update Privacy policy and also included privacy policy in app login page as well as drawer menu.

then app was live. but today app has been removed from playstore and receiving this message.
[Playstore Remove Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Wrjv.png)

Next steps: Submit your app for another review

1. Review the issues and any policy page(s) shown above.
   For issues related to Privacy Policy and Prominent Disclosure, refer to the “Privacy Policy” and “Prominent Disclosure & Consent Requirement” sections in the User Data policy. Additionally, for further guidance on prominent disclosure, review best practices for prominent disclosure.
2. Make appropriate changes to your app, and be sure to address the issues identified above.
3. Upon making the required changes, check if your app is compliant with all Developer Program Policies.
4. For violations requiring APK/App Bundle level updates, deactivate the noncompliant version and upload a compliant version with an incremented version code.
   In addition to your Production release, if you have other release types that you use for testing and/or quality assurance checks (for example, Internal test, Closed, Open), please make required changes and update those tracks as well.
5. For creating a new release, sign in to Play Console, go to App bundle explorer and select the track with the policy issue (Internal / Closed / Open testing / Production). Click Manage track > Create new release.
   If the release with the violating app bundles/APKs are in a draft state, discard the release.
   Otherwise, add the policy-compliant version of app bundles/APKs.
   Make sure that the non-compliant version is under the "Not included" section of this release.
   Enter a release name and click Save. Once saved, click Review release, and then proceed to roll out the release to 100% and completely deactivate the non-compliant APK.
6. If the noncompliant versions are released to multiple tracks, repeat step 5 in each track.